# ejs error 'include' requires the 'filename' option

Tags: node.js, ejs

**PROBLEM**

by some online examples you may use syntax like this

```js
<%- include hello-world %>
```

or even you can use

```js
<%- include('hello-world'); %>
```

you may get error that include missing filename

```
Exception occurred: Error: `include` requires the 'filename' option.
```

Q where is the problem if my syntax is right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer is in backend "**file path**"

but even if you used the proper path you get an error too

```js
var fs = require('fs');
ejs.render(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/templates/include.ejs', 'utf8'), {});
```

right answer is "**use renderFile**"

```js
ejs.renderFile(__dirname + '/templates/include.ejs', {}, function(err, result) {
    if (!err) {
        res.end(result);
    }
    else {
        res.end(err.toString());
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

---

ref

- https://github.com/tj/ejs/issues/138

Answer (score 0):

It's 03/2023 and EJS latest version is [v3.1.8](https://github.com/mde/ejs/tree/v3.1.8).

Info you are using EJS@v2 such as v2.5.4 you may want to read this:

**EJS has a bug on relative paths detection that impacts windows but not unix systems that results in above error message** [as you can see here](https://github.com/mde/ejs/blob/v2.5.4/lib/ejs.js#L111)

Upgrading to [version 2.7.4](https://github.com/mde/ejs/blob/v2.7.4/lib/ejs.js#L136) will fix the issue.

If you are using version3 this shouldn't be an issue.